# How to delete elastic search indices older than 30 days using dev tool commands

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I want to delete kibana indices that are older than 30 days from today using kibana dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [Index life cycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) to automate it.

**EDIT** You can use the `http://es-host:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,creation.date.string` to find the indices creation time of all indices in your cluster, once you have all the indices, you can delete them using the [delete indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html).

Comment: But currently, the server is full and I have to delete the indices manually

Comment: Nope I am not able to delete exactly 30 days backlogs, I want to have only 30 days logs and want to delete older indices than 30 days .

Comment: my logs are stored in the below format yellow open logstash-0020.37 kojvPxpyQx2LVK1835Ldgw 1 1      10   0    88kb    88kb

Comment: @VVR i didn't get you, you mentioned you want to delete indices not logs older than 30 days